# Search a keyword with a space in it using query rules SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, user-profile-property

I have a simple requirement to search based on phone numbers.

Phone numbers of users are stored in their user profiles.

The managed property for phone number is `People:PhoneNumber`

I have made a query rule to bring people in everything tab as a promoted results. Below is the rule.

```
PhoneNumber:"{subjectTerms}" OR PhoneNumber:"{subjectTerms}*"
```

Following works fine:

1. 1234567890
2. 1234
3. 123*

**Following does not work**

1. 1234 56789

How can I allow phone numbers having space in it?

Comment: Do you have any user profiles where the phone number has a space in it? Search finds anything that contains whatever you type in. If anything contains "1234" it will find it. Same goes for if anything contains "1234 56789", if not, it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes there is one user whose profile is set to contain 1234 56789. 
I ran the incremental crawl. I hope it does not need any full crawls as its just data change?

Comment: Incremental crawl should be sufficient, yes. Try a full crawl nonetheless just to be sure.

Comment: I am afraid this full crawl dint work totally. There are few users with spaces  in phone number comes in search result, but not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how crawl works.

If you have `PhoneNumber` in these format:

1. 1234567890
2. 1234 567890
3. 123 4567 890
4. 123 456 7890

When crawling, every sign or space `" ", "-", "_", "(", ")"` is like delimiter and it is putted in new place inside array.

For example: for 1. it will be array[0] with (1234567890), 
for 2. will be array[0 and 1] with (1234 and 567890) because space 
and for 3. and 4. it will be array[0, 1 and 2] because two spaces.

When you search for example `PhoneNumber:"123*"` you get all four.

If you search for ex. `PhoneNumber:"1234*"` you will get only two (1. and 2.).

If you search for ex. `PhoneNumber:"12345*"` you will get only one (1.) because only 1. contains all chars in one place.

If you search for ex. `PhoneNumber:"123 456*"` you will get two  (3. and 4.).

I hope it's a little more clearly for you how crawl works.

Comment: What if you search for PhoneNumber:" 456*"? And NOT PhoneNumber:" 456"?